# Compile using latexmk in emacs

Tags: compiling, emacs, latexmk

In the accepted answer in for [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199678/how-to-call-latexmk-in-emacs-and-jump-to-next-error) it is suggested how to add `latexmk` support to emacs. If I get it right, compiling the `.tex` file should be assigned to `C-c C-c`. However this doesn't work for me and I have to go to the menu and click the `latexmk` option.

My question is basically, how do I make the `latexmk` the default engine for the emacs+auctex?

EDIT 1: When hitting `C-c C-c`, and then typing `latexmk` I get the desired result, i.e. it compiles using latexmk. Thus, maybe a more specific question is how to set latexmk to be the default script/compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, look at `TeX-command-list` to ensure that it has an entry for `latexmk`.  If not, you need to add a line to this variable to allow the executable to be invoked by Auctex; unfortunately this variable is not well-documented (see [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Selecting-a-Command.html)); I explain a little later.

Second, the default program is specified by the variable `TeX-command-default`.  Change this to the identifier used by `TeX-command-list`, that is, the string just before the specification of the `latexmk` command.

E.g., if one of the elements in `TeX-command-list` is shown (which you can see using `C-h v`):

```
 ("Latex Make" "latexmk %(-pdf) %t" TeX-run-TeX)
```

then `TeX-command-default` needs to be `"Latex Make"`.

### The Auctex variable `TeX-command-default`

This variable isn't, as I said, well-documented.  It should be a list of lists, each of which takes the form:

```
 '("Handle" "external-command %(switches) %(arguments)" Auctex-handler)
```

where `Handle` introduces a handle for facility to be run from the `C-c C-c` dialog, so the list of handles in `TeX-command-default` is the list of possible completions at this prompt.   The second option is a form specifying the executable to be run, and `Auctex-handler` is an Elisp function that handles the process and invokes the external command.  `TeX-run-TeX` and `TeX-run-command` are the most common handlers, but there are special handlers for Bibtex, the spell checkers, etc.

Comment: This gave me a hint. In `AUCTeX Group->TeX Command->TeX Command List` I added (at the beginning of the list) an entry named `LaTeXmk` with command `latexmk -pdf %t` and value `TeX-run-command`. Then, after `C-c C-c` I could type `LaTeXmk` and it ran the right script and produced the right result. How can I make it the default? Assign a some key shortcut?

Comment: How do I set this variable? I couldn't find it in `AUCTeX Group->TeX Command`...

Comment: It's a buffer-local variable, so you can't customise it.  You can see its contents using H-v in the buffer you are interested in.  You are best off setting it in your file using an Emacs local variable, but the following will set the value in all TeX buffers if you add it to your preamble: (add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "LaTeX Make"))), changing "LaTeX Make" to whatever identifier is used in TeX-command-list.

Comment: Seems that is produced what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesStewart: What is `H-v`? `C-h v`?

Comment: @SabreWolfy - Yes, the variable-show dialogue.  I'll fix my answer.

Comment: What's the difference between `TeX-run-command` and `TeX-run-TeX`? `%(-pdf)` (doesn't work for me) and just `-pdf` by itself (which works)? How do I get latexmk to jump to an error in my document like the other commands do?

Comment: @Andrew (sorry for delay- I've been away from Stack Exchange recently): TeX-run-TeX is a wrapper around TeX-run-command that tries to use its knowledge of the Tex format to to parse logs - you will only get jumping to errors with TeX-run-TeX.  I don't know why "latexmk %(-pdf)" isn't working - try "latexmk -pdf %s", but you won't be able to get DVI output if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you simply want to get all of the necessary file compiled, not necessarily by `latexmk`. The simplest way to achieve this is to run `C-c C-a`, which executes `TeX-command-run-all`.