# Emacs-org-mode and latexmk

Tags: compiling, emacs, latexmk, org-mode

After getting to know [org mode](http://orgmode.org/) here, I tried it out. It seems to be, indeed, very helpful. However, I want it to work smoothly with LaTeX, and as a compiling script I want to use `latexmk`.

I followed the instruction [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#using-xelatex-for-pdf-export) trying to make org-mode use `latexmk` as the compiling engine/script. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. The resulting `.tex` file is perfect and I can manually compile it using `latexmk`, but it won't work directly.

Comment: @Dror: *"After getting to know org mode here"* , could you add a link please. I don't know it and like to getting to know it as well.

Comment: @Martin: I added a link. By _"here"_ I meant in this/our community :)

Comment: @Dror: I thought so but couldn't find it first *here* on tex.sx. Just a tip: you might call it "Emacs org-mode" in the title and the text to make it more clear.

Comment: There's not really enough information here to help.  Maybe Emacs can't find the latexmk binary?  Check the value of the load-path Emacs variable.  If not, can you see if any external processes are invoked by emacs?

Comment: @Charles: I'm afraid that I don't know how to verify this. I added `(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/texbin/")` to my `.emacs`. In this directory there is a link `latexmk`. How can I check the external process? Thnx!!

Comment: @Dror: If you have Dtrace or similar on your system, it's very easy, you can log all new processes over a period of time using newproc.d.  If not, it can be a bit tricky to catch processes as they are invoked; a trick is to put a wrapperbin directory at the front of load-path which is a wrapper for the binaries you want to log, and which logs a message before and after calling the real executable, e.g., `echo "start: $0 $*" >> logfile; /usr/texbin/latexmk "$@"; xstat=$?; echo "end $xstat: $0 $*" >> logfile; exit $xstat` as the payload of a shell script called $wrapperbindir/latexmk on Unix.

Comment: @Charles: I do have dtrace but I don't know how to use it. However, consider the edit in my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10561/compile-using-latexmk-in-emacs I guess it means that emacs can find latexmk. The problem is making org-mode find it and use it as well.

Comment: AFAIK, all Emacs packages that access outside executables use the Elisp primitive call-process, which uses the variable exec-path, and don't fiddle with it, so this should not be the problem.  Dtrace will tell you what arguments are passed to latexmk, which is the next thing we want to know: check that you have the  newproc.d script, and run it as root in a terminal window.  Then invoke export to PDF and look at the output of the newproc.d process.  You should see the invocation of latexmk: what arguments are passed?  What happens when you run latexmk by hand with these arguments.

Comment: @Charles: I'm sorry but I don't know how to implement your tips. I'd be happy to know what org-mode is doing when I hit `C-c C-e p`. This will probably be helpful.

Comment: It runs org-export-as-pdf, which calls the commands in the list of strings, org-latex-to-pdf.  Maybe changing this variable will work?

Comment: Sorry this isn't as a comment, but I don't have the rep!

You might be better off asking on the `org-mode` users mailing list [here][1].  They are generally pretty quick to respond with useful information.


  [1]: http://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode "here"

Comment: Thnx! I tried this as well.

Comment: When you compile your document in org-mode with "C-c C-e d", Emacs/org-mode should create a buffer in the background called "*Org PDF LaTeX Output*". This is a log of the compilation process. You should be able to switch to it using C-x b (or just see if it's there in the "Buffers" menu on the menubar). Can you see any error messages in there about where latexmk or some other aspect of the compile process is failing?

Comment: There is not C-c C-e d any more in the default org setup. Perhaps now it is C-c C-e l p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The *org-mode* mailing list was useful!](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-02/msg00373.html) I added `(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process (list "latexmk -f -pdf %f"))` to my `.emacs` file and then `C-c C-e d` worked as expected, producing the PDF using `latexmk`.

**Note** if org-mode-version > 8.0 `org-latex-to-pdf-process` has been renamed to `org-latex-pdf-process`

Comment: I had to use "%f" instead of "%s" but thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 9):

In Org mode 8, the variable is renamed. As Shitikanth commented, I needed %f, so in org 8:

`(setq org-latex-pdf-process (list "latexmk -f -pdf %f"))`

Comment: This should also include `-output-directory=%o`.