# Problems with .bbl in org-mode

Tags: bibtex, emacs, org-mode

I use Emacs's org-mode to draft papers. I also use the [`tufte-latex` package](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/).

Currently my `.emacs` looks like this:

```lisp
(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process
     '("xelatex -interaction nonstopmode %f"
       "xelatex -interaction nonstopmode %f")
)
(require 'org-latex)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-indent-mode 1)))
(unless (boundp 'org-export-latex-classes)
(setq org-export-latex-classes nil))

(add-to-list 'org-export-latex-classes
  '("tufte-handout" 
"\\documentclass[justified]{tufte-handout}
\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\\usepackage{fontspec}
\\usepackage{graphicx} 
\\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\\usepackage{geometry}
\\usepackage{multicol}
\\pagestyle{empty}
\\title{}
      [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
      [NO-PACKAGES]"
("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
     ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
     ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
     ("\\subsubsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsubsection*{%s}")
     ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
     ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Now I am trying to export file called `tnc.org`. There is a  `tnc.bib` file in the same directory. I include it in the `.org` file thus:

```
\bibliography{tnc}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

However, when I try to export using org-mode, I get the following warning:

```
No file tnc.bbl.
Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
```

The paper renders otherwise ok, except there are no sidenotes or bibliography.

What do I do?

Comment: Are the entries in org-latex-to-pdf-process the commands that get run to convert your org or LaTeX file into a final PDF? If so, I don't see anything that would run BibTeX as part of the process. [BibTeX's usage page](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/) uses four commands: one LaTeX run, one BibTeX run, and two more LaTeX runs.

Comment: Indeed, Mike, I changed the export function to this:

(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process
     '("xelatex %f && bibtex %f && xelatex %f && xelatex %f"))

and it works. Thanks.

However I have a newish problem: in the bibliography, the numbers corresponding to the citations do not show up. Why is this?

Comment: @MikeRenfro Can you turn your comment into an answer? Maybe adding that numbers before references depend on the bibliographic style used.

Comment: @egreg comment converted to answer.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than hard coding a build sequence you can let [latexmk](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) take care of the build process. This will make a more flexible solution that works for other document types than the one you specified. [To have Org-mode export to pdf by latexmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10562/emacs-org-mode-and-latexmk) you can add the following line to your .emacs:

```lisp
(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process (list "latexmk -pdf %f"))
```

Comment: to generate bbl with latexmk, '-bibtex' option is needed, which means: `(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process (list "latexmk -pdf -bibtex %f"))`

Answer (score 5):

Change your org-latex-to-pdf-process setting to

```lisp
(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process '("xelatex %f && bibtex %f && xelatex %f && xelatex %f"))
```

or something similar. This sequence of commands is taken from the [BibTeX usage page](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/).

As to your bibliography numbers not appearing, this would depend on the `\bibliographystyle` you're using. A [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in a separate question would help narrow down what's going wrong there.