# How to get BibTeX to work with Org mode LaTeX export?

Tags: bibtex, emacs, org-mode

I am trying to get Emacs (24.3.1), Org-mode (8.0.3, from ELPA) and BibTeX (from TeX Live 2012) to work together.
I have followed the instructions under the **Bibliography** section in http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html but after exporting the document to LaTeX, compiling to PDF, and opening the result (with key sequence `C-c C-e l o` in the latest Org mode) I see a question mark instead of a citation (i.e., **[?]**) which means that the reference was not resolved by LaTeX. In fact, checking the `Org PDF LaTeX Output` buffer, I see the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Tappert77' on page 3 undefined on input line 43.

No file org-bib-test.bbl.
[3] (.//org-bib-test.aux) 

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

It looked to me that probably Org-mode was looking for a `.bib` file with the same base name as the `.org` file but renaming the `.bib` file and updating the `\bibliography` line did not solve the problem.

Here are two minimal `.org` and `.bib` files that together can be used to reproduce the behavior described above:

**`org-bib-test.org`**

```
* Tests
** Test1 slide
   - This is test1 \cite{Tappert77}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{org-bib-test-refs}
```

The following, using `#+LATEX_HEADER`, gives the same result:

**`org-bib-test.org`**

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \bibliographystyle{plain}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \bibliography{org-bib-test-refs}

* Tests
** Test1 slide
   - This is test1 \cite{Tappert77}.
```

**`org-bib-test-refs.bib`**

```
@incollection {Tappert77,
AUTHOR = {Tappert, Fred D.},
TITLE = {The parabolic approximation method},
BOOKTITLE = {Wave propagation and underwater acoustics ({W}orkshop,
              {M}ystic, {C}onn., 1974)},
PAGES = {224--287. Lecture Notes in Phys., Vol. 70},
PUBLISHER = {Springer},
ADDRESS = {Berlin},
YEAR = {1977},
MRCLASS = {76.41 (86.41)},
}
```

Currently I am using the following **ugly** hack to get the references resolved: I generate the `.bbl` file from the `.bib` file (using a minimal `.tex` file) and then I `\include` the resulting `.bbl` file directly in my `.org` file. This is rather cumbersome and of course requires that I regenerate the `.bbl` file every time I make a change to the `.bib` file. Although this process can be automated in Emacs by writing a lisp function to encapsulate these actions, I'd rather solve the problem than streamline a hack.

**Edit**
I have checked the `.tex` file generated by Org mode. It *does* have the following necessary lines exported in it:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{org-bib-test-refs}
```

Comment: For future readers, I posted what I believe to be the answer on the Org mode mailing list, here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-05/msg00791.html

Comment: I can confirm that, disregarding efficiency (which is another story to be fair), the solution suggested by @G.JayKerns works. I will accept it if he posts it here as an answer.

Answer (score 15):

@G.JayKerns has a perfectly good solution in the comments, but since this question has been a while without an answer, I'll fill it in.  The important elisp variable is `org-latex-pdf-process`, which can work with a number of settings.  I have mine set up as something like:

```lisp
(setq org-latex-pdf-process (list
   "latexmk -pdflatex='lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode' -pdf -f  %f"))
```

That's a simplification since I set the actual variable dynamically based on some other orgmode macro lines, but the basic idea should work.

You can use explicit multiple iterations or a build process like `latexmk` or `rubber` within `org-latex-pdf-process`.  Use what you would at the command line and check the log in the `*Org PDF LaTeX Output*` buffer if you get errors.

The org-mode file should look like this:
`org-bib-test.org`

```
* Tests
** Test1 slide
   - This is test1 \cite{Tappert77}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{org-bib-test-refs}
```

Put your bibtex in the file `org-bib-test-refs.bib` and run `C-c C-e l o` and you should be good.

Answer (score 9):

This answer from

[Problems with .bbl in org-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32348/problems-with-bbl-in-org-mode)

```lisp
(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process (list "latexmk -pdf %f"))
```

worked for me

Comment: Is `org-latex-to-pdf-process` a typo? Because, only `org-latex-pdf-process` exists on my system.

Comment: `org-latex-pdf-process` works for me, the other not. Thank you @MaliRemorker

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation for `org-latex-pdf-process` in org-mode version 8.2.5h (February 10, 2014):

> By default, Org uses 3 runs of `pdflatex` to do the processing.
>   If you have texi2dvi on your system and if that does not cause
>   the infamous egrep/locale bug:
>
> http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-texinfo/2010-03/msg00031.html
>
> then `texi2dvi` is the superior choice as it automates the LaTeX
>   build process by calling the "correct" combinations of
>   auxiliary programs.  Org does offer `texi2dvi` as one of the
>   customize options.  Alternatively, `rubber` and `latexmk` also
>   provide similar functionality.  The latter supports `biber' out
>   of the box.

The customization buffer offers a value menu that includes `texi2dvi`, so it can easily be set through that interface. If you prefer to set the value in your .emacs, you can use the following:

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process (quote ("texi2dvi -p -b -V %f")))
```

Comment: `texi2dvi` I could find. But `(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process (list "latexmk -pdf %f"))` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Because bibtex usually uses `\cite{some_reference}` there is a conflict involving reftex in org-mode where the usual bib{some_reference} is used. To get round this I define a my-org2pdf-export, which works for me using emacs-24 and org 8.3. I then an org file using reftex to call references and then use M-x my-org2pdf-export RET when I want to export to a pdf file.

```
;;; Begin "my-org2pdf-export"
;;;
;;; Define bib2cite
(defun my-bib2cite ()
"change bib to cite"
(interactive)
(let ((case-fold-search t)) ; or nil
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (search-forward "bib:" nil t)
(replace-match "cite:" t t))))
;;;
;;; Define cite2bib
(defun my-cite2bib ()
"change cite to bib"
(interactive)
(let ((case-fold-search t)) ; or nil
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (search-forward "cite:" nil t)
(replace-match "bib:" t t))))
;;;
;;; Change bib: to cite: in .org file
;;; Then call org-export-dispatch and 
;;; then change cite: back to bib: 
;;; to leave original .org file unchanged.
(defun my-export-org ()
"export settings"
(interactive)
(my-bib2cite) ;; Change bib: to cite:
(org-export-dispatch) ;; Call the dispatcher
(my-cite2bib) ;; Change cite: back to bib:
(save-buffer);; Save file again
) ;; End bracket
;;; End "my-org2pdf-export".
```

Comment: This post/discussion would help me greatly if it were current. Or is it current enough? Or what parts are not current? I'm on org-mode 9.0.2.