# Automatically run Latex command after saving .tex file in Emacs

Tags: emacs, automation

How can I have Emacs call the Latex command every time after I save my .tex file?

Thanks

A solution: while playing with ELisp and looking around, I added this to .emacs and it seems to work quite well (just don't press `C-x C-s` too much frequently, say every 5 secs):

```
(defun run-latex ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((process (TeX-active-process))) (if process (delete-process process)))
    (let ((TeX-save-query nil)) (TeX-save-document ""))
    (TeX-command-menu "LaTeX"))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") #'run-latex)))
```

The advantage of this solution over latexmk is that it is quicker to put working because I don't have to customize anything (and risking making mistakes). Also, in case I want to remove it, I only have to comment the last line `(add-hook ...` in your .emacs.

Anyway, latexmk seems also another interesting path I will try when I have more time.

Thanks for your answers and help.

Comment: I don't see why you can't just call the latex command which in turn causes a save of the file. Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: In that case you have to always type "y" when asked for to save the file before the latex command runs. But, your solution would be good if I knew how to configure Emacs to save the file every time before the latex command is run. Do you know how?

Comment: I hit "save" quite frequently when I'm typing my documents (and of course don't want to run LaTeX each time). Better safe than sorry. :)

Comment: @mljrg If you add (setq TeX-save-query nil) to your .emacs file then C-c C-c will not ask for confirmation before saving the file. It will save automatically on compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please search this forum for `latexmk`, which does exactly what you ask.

---

EDIT: See here: [Compile using latexmk in emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10561/compile-using-latexmk-in-emacs)

There are more threads in this forum, if you search for 'latexmk' and 'emacs'.

Comment: That seems to be one way, but I have everything already configured in Emacs (that is, I have source links, direct and inverse search working, etc), so I would prefer a simple solution inside Emacs. Is there one?

Comment: @mljrg: Run Latexmk in preview-continuous mode instead of LaTeX. If you are using AUCTeX it’s not difficult to add a new command to the list inspected by `C-c C-c`.

Comment: @mhp But in that case I still have to do `C-x C-s` then `C-c C-c`don't I? I just wanted to do `C-x C-s`and have the file saved and Latex run.

Comment: @mljrg: No, once you’ve started Latexmk in preview-continuous mode it recompiles your document every time you press `C-x C-s`.

Comment: @mhp Can you tell me how to do that? I changed the entry AUCTeX\Tex Command Group\Latex Command to "latexmk -pvc" but it did not worked. Thanks

Comment: @mljrg: I don’t use AUCTeX. But according to the [documenation](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.pdf) (page 45), you simply have to add an element to `TeX-command-list` and update `TeX-command-default`.

Comment: @mhp I will accept this answer, and will try latexmk later. Meanwhile I will skip with the above ELisp code, which is working and doesn't require messing up the configurations. Thanks!

Comment: @Keks: This isn't a forum `;)`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/about

Answer (score 1):

Since my elisp skills are rather poor, I can only suggest a general Idea. Using `TeX-sace-query` and/or `TeX-sace-document` you can re-bind `C-x C-s` to first save the file(s) and then run your `TeX-run-TeX` with the appropriate parameter.

As a side remark, I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'tex-buf)
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
         (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdf %t" 'TeX-master-file)
         master-file)
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (minibuffer-message "latexmk done"))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-0") #'run-latexmk)))
```

which binds `C-0` to SAVE and then run latexmk.

Comment: I have added this to .emacs `(defun my-run-latex ()
 (interactive)
 (TeX-command "LaTeX" 'TeX-master-file -1))
  
(add-hook 'after-save-hook  'my-run-latex)`, it is working, but I am getting an error "Wrong type argument: stringp, nil" and I don't know why. Also I would like to check if the file extension is .tex, and only in this case the hook would call latex on the file.

Comment: Your solution runs synchronously and blocks if I save the file two times in a row.

Comment: Your solution was helpful to reach mine above. Thanks!

Comment: @mljrg: Usually I'm using the "preview" option of latexmk, and just save the file. BTW, with latexmk you hardly have to customize anything...