# Emacs + SyncTex + Evince

Tags: emacs, evince

I am trying to setup forward search and inverse search between Emacs 24.3.1 and Auctex under Ubuntu 14.04.

Forward search is working fine by enable TeX-source-correlate-mode in Emacs but while performing this search, the focus also moves to PDF. I would like to keep the focus on .tex file during forward search. Is there any hack or command available to achieve this.

I would also like to setup inverse-search. I have tried Ctrl + left click but it doesn't work.

Comment: For inverse search, have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29813/setup-synctex-with-emacs For your focus issue, it seems like something you will have to set up in your window manager, or by adding a parameter to your call of `evince`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to (i) tell Emacs what is your document viewer, and then (ii) configure the document viewer to collaborate with Emacs to use the inverse search, that is, Ctrl+left click.

I don't think that Evince offers configuration option directly. I prefer more to work with Okular than Evince. The following post describes how to activate the forwards and reverse search on Auctex+Okular. I hope that you find it helpful: 
[How to configure Emacs and AUCTeX to perform Forward and Inverse Search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161797/how-to-configure-emacs-and-auctex-to-perform-forward-and-inverse-search)