# Howto use Okular with Emacs Auctex?

Tags: emacs, auctex, okular

When I follow [subham soni's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161797/how-to-configure-emacs-and-auctex-to-perform-forward-and-inverse-search) instructions to connect emacs with Okular, I get the error message "Symbol's function definition is void: nil" when emacs tries to call the viewer "Command: (default View)" Any idea why this happens ?

My complete .emacs file is the following:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.  
 '(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" ("okular %o") "okular --unique %o#src:%n%b"))))
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote (((output-dvi has-no-display-manager) "dvi2tty") ((output-dvi style-pstricks) "dvips and gv") (output-pdf "Okular") (output-dvi "xdvi") (output-pdf "Evince") (output-html "xdg-open"))))
 '(delete-selection-mode nil)
 '(mark-even-if-inactive t)
 '(scroll-bar-mode (quote right))
 '(transient-mark-mode 1))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Comment: Please, post the content of your init file, at least the part relative to the setting of `TeX-view-program-selection`.

Comment: which file exactly do I have to post and where should it be located ?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html

Comment: @giordano I uploaded the entire .emacs file

Comment: Six years later @giordano s comment still leads to the correct solution: Choose okular by customizing TeX-view-programm-selection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the line

```lisp
'(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" ("okular %o") "okular --unique %o#src:%n%b"))))
```

It has a wrong format and anyway is useless if you use a recent AUCTeX version (11.88 or above), Okular is correctly configured out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. Though I  don't understand why it was wrong. I followed the guide from the link..

Comment: If it answers your question please mark it as accepted.  You added the line `okular --unique %o#src:%n%b` to the `One executable` field, not the `Command` one as indicated by subham soni.  Anyway, there is no need to change Okular setting nowadays.