# Highlighting forward search in Okular

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search, okular

I have a functional setup that does bidirectional search between `emacs (auctex)` and `okular` but lacks the highlighting of the position in pdf.

In "conventional" editors, e.g. texstudio, when doing forward search the pdf is highlighted with a yellow background helping me to locate the correct position in pdf.

Can achieve this with auctex-okular? Currently forward search jumps to the correct page in okular but it is my job to identify the exact point.

My current setup, inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161797/22492) QA, is as follow:

```
 '(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" "okular --unique %o#src:%n%b"))))
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((engine-omega "dvips and gv") (output-dvi "xdvi") (output-pdf "Okular") (output-html "xdg-open"))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately my config using okular is gone because I use pdf-tools since some years. Under Linux it is fast and has one advantage, at least for me. Clicking on a certain letter in the PDF moves the focus to this letter in the *.tex file, so I can correct typos quickly.

Comment: Generally this is solved a different way by every user since there are so many ways to init Emacs however the official line (which I have not always found to be fully accurate especially beware that cut and paste of punctuation can go wrong (reverse call should be `"emacsclient -a emacs --no-wait +%l %f"` ) at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX#toc27 Okular.pdf indicates page and name-dest only but I think that is old info and would like you expect to go to the line not just the page, are you using an uptodate version

Comment: @KJO thanks for the comment. My okular setting is exactly as you have. Indeed the backward search is working fine but the problem is the forward search. That is, I want the pdf get highlighted so that I can easily identify the changes. I rephrased the question to address the ambiguity presented in the original question.