# How to increase (relevant) verbosity of compilation errors with Emacs+AucTeX?

Tags: errors, texmaker, emacs, auctex

I often debug LaTeX files and Emacs+AUCTeX does not show many informations about errors.

I always have the following message in the minibuffer:

```
LaTeX errors in `*~/my/file output*'. Use C-c ` to display.
```

and if I press `` C-c ` ``

```
TeX-error: Error occured after last TeX file closed
```

which is completely useless.

If I want to track errors, I have to change buffer (go to output buffer) and looking by myself where is the problematic part inside a big file where 99% of informations are not errors.

At the opposite, Texmaker shows precisely the error message as you can see:

[image]

Therefore sometimes I use Texmaker to debug LaTeX file instead of Emacs.

*I'm looking any solution to improve the way Emacs notify errors. How can have a concise view of errors which is really useful to debug with Emacs?*

Comment: (For now, it appears.) Ignore that message regarding how to access the errors.  On a long enough compile via `C-c C-c`, you'll see echoed in the mini-buffer `Type \`C-c C-l' to display results of compilation.` So, use `C-c C-l`, which will split the main buffer into two and open in the lower a file called something like `*~/<path to file> output*`, which is essentially your console output.

Comment: You can search for lines that begin with `!` to see errors, too.  I've had this problem before, but I don't recall how I fixed it.  Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124259/17423 help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since version 11.88, [AUCTeX comes with an error overview](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Error-overview.html), accessible via `TeX-error-overview`.

There are two possible setups: overview in the same frame of the TeX buffer and in a separate dedicated frame.  This is how it looks like:

> **Same frame setup**
>   [image: AUCTeX error overview, same frame]

---

> **Separate frame setup**
>   [image: AUCTeX error overview, separate frame]

You can visit an error by clicking on its message or pressing <kbd>RET</kbd>.  <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> can also be used to go to the next or previous error.  Other suggestions welcome `:-)`

The message

```
TeX-error: Error occured after last TeX file closed
```

refers to a difficulty for AUCTeX to correctly parse the output log.  This issue should have been already fixed in version 11.90.

Comment: Ah, nice to know!

Comment: Thanks for all these informations. I will wait the next release of AUCTeX. If I may say something about this (great) patch : perhaps you should allow the possibility to open the error list inside a buffer rather than a frame. It's easier to manage buffers than frames.

Comment: @ppr  I'm working on it, also because non-graphical displays don't support multiple frames.  Anyway I find much easier to use a second frame (as `ediff` does), switching between frames requires only `ALT + TAB` in most window managers.

Comment: @ppr  I managed to make the error overview open in the same frame of the TeX buffer, see the updated answer `;-)`.

Comment: Nice! I'm waiting the update of Debian sid AUCTeX package. Thanks a lot for your hard work.

Comment: @giordano I'm curious -- how do you achieve the "Same frame format" -- I have been searching for exactly that!