# How can I configure AUCTeX to automatically switch to the compilation log after hitting C-c?

Tags: compiling, auctex

I would like to see the compilation results after hitting C-c, however, AUCTeX always asks me to additionally hit C-l to swich to the log window and automatically scroll down. I would prefer C-c to include this step.

Comment: Do you have AUCTeX 11.88? Would you prefer instead to automatically open an overview of the errors and warnings?

Comment: Yes, 11.88, an overview would be even better than a full log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since AUCTeX 11.88 there a new errors and warnings overview (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185823/31416). To automatically open it after running a TeX engine set the variable `TeX-error-overview-open-after-TeX-run` to t.  To do that, add the following code to your init file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-error-overview-open-after-TeX-run t)
```

Here is how the overview looks like:

> [image: AUCTeX error overview, same frame]

You can open the error overview whenever you want with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `TeX-error-overview` <kbd>RET</kbd>