# How to modify Emacs/AUCTeX to make for useful debugging?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am writing a book-length text using LaTeX. I sometimes find difficulty in finding/understanding the various errors when compiling. I am using Emacs/AUCTeX. Is there a way of modifying emacs to make debugging easier?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. AUCTeX provides both information from the log and, occasionally, a more descriptive help message. Do you want something  moreeven informative?

Comment: Is this a problem with included files? You may want to run `latex` with the option `-file-line-error`. If that's not to the point, please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I think OP wants a "condensed" log message to be displayed, i.e. with only errors & warnings, and the corresponding lines. If this is the case, then this question should probably be marked as [a duplicate of this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185819/34551).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use the [compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html) from emacs with `M-x compile`. Then you can write the command you want to use, for example `pdflatex doc.tex`.

A new buffer will open: `*compilation*` in this buffer you can use `tab` to go to the next warning/error which indicate the line where the problem occurs.

by hitting `enter`, you'll open a buffer where the error occurs at the correct line. So you have two buffer open, one with your (La)TeX file and the other with the log:

[image]

Comment: What's the difference with compiling with AUCTeX, which, in addition, provides more descriptive information for common errors and warnings not available elsewhere?

Comment: @giordano I do not use AUCTeX. This is why I presented this solution. Compiling with AUCTeX and following the path I presented should be a solution too

Comment: If one really wants to manually type `pdflatex doc.tex`, lose forward/inverse search and the possibility to view [a nice formatted list of error and warnings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185823/31416) (in addition to the descriptive help messages already mentioned above), and stop at the first error encountered (so one has to compile n times to fix n errors, instead of compiling just once and spot errors all together), then probably yes, this is a solution too.