# Auctex and beamer: TeX-error: Error occured after last TeX file closed

Tags: beamer, emacs, auctex

I use Auctex to create a beamer document. Frequently I run into this rather uninformative error message:

TeX-error: Error occured after last TeX file closed

I found a similar thread [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124246/uninformative-error-message-when-using-auctex) and followed the suggestions to include this

```
(setq LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -file-line-error %S%(PDFout)")))
```

in my .emacs. This solved the issue for me in the past but does not help in all cases. How to proceed If I still get this error?

Comment: Got that sometimes too, never been bothered enough to investigate it. What you can do when it happens is open the log file `<document>.log` and `C-s` for `error`, for example. There will be a few useless matches in the preamble, then you should find your error. Without knowing what was the error and where it occurred exactly, it may be hard to give you a definite answer.

Comment: Thanks. This seems a bit "quick and dirty" but it is effective in getting a hint about the error. In this case the error was caused by a missing \end{}. Is there anything I can do to get helpful error messages without inspecting *.log?

Comment: A missing end is a lost cause as far as I understand: it is perfectly legal to open an environment in an input file, and close it in the main file; so indeed "the error appeared after the last file closed". Also, (afaicr) this error appears at the next end environment, which can very well be the end of the document!

Comment: However, maybe auctex could be patched to display the error message even if it doesn't know where the error appeared (or if the error appeared in a non-document file... I won't edit a .sty to fix an error in my code...). Maybe that's something that could be suggested on the auctex development mailing list: http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.devel

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because sounds like a bug report for auctex