# TeX error: "Error occurred after last TeX file closed" How to fix this with emacs?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I have recently started to use Emacs editor to type latex documents. For a while everything was going smooth and fine but one good day I got this annoying error message while compiling my document. It says there is some error and tells to use key combo `C-c'`   to view the error. But when I do so, the message "Error occurred after last TeX file closed" keeps appearing. It doesn't show the actual error. What should I do to get the proper error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always get the log by typing `C-c C-l` after running LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeTeX (forgot something?). Then have a look at the first (!) error message.

And for the rest, please see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124259/4736 .