# AUCTex's line number information does not work

Tags: miktex, auctex

My setup: AUCTex 11.89.4, MikTeX 2.9 64bit, Emacs 24 on Windows 10. It has no serious customization other than setting the viewer to SumatraPDF and some colors and fonts.

The problem: I compile a long multipart file (a book) with pdflatex from inside AUCTex. I on purpose add a bogus command `\dasdasa` on some line. AUCTex properly recognizes the error, which is reported by pdflatex with error file and line number information

```
photons.tex:579: Undefined control sequence
```

but AUCTex is unable to find the location of the error in the file. It systematically goes to the wrong line! Any hints?

Comment: To complete the information: Emacs was installed from GNU's repo, AUCTeX was installed using MELPA stable repository. It all is rather easy to do, I am really happy for the outcome other than for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with MiKTeX.  You have to complain with MiKTeX developer because the *tex programs included in that distribution give fewer details when one uses the `file:line:error` message style, that is supposed to give more information.  You can add a comment to this bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2310/

In order to workaround this issue you have to set `TeX-file-line-error` to `nil` by either using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX-file-line-error` <kbd>RET</kbd>, or adding the following line to your init file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-file-line-error nil)
```

See also the [Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#FAQ) in AUCTeX manual:

> **8**. Why does `TeX-next-error` (<kbd>C-c `</kbd>) fail?
>
> If `TeX-file-line-error` is set to
>   `nil` (not the default), these sort of failures might be related to the
>   the fact that when writing the log file, TeX puts information related
>   to a file, including error messages, between a pair of parentheses. In
>   this scenario AUCTeX determines the file where the error happened by
>   parsing the log file and counting the parentheses. This can fail when
>   there are other, unbalanced parentheses present.
>
> Activating so-called `file:line:error` messages for the log file usually
>   solves this issue, as these kind of messages are are easier to parse;
>   however, they may lack some details. Activation can be done either in
>   the configuration of your TeX system (consult its manual to see where
>   this is) or by simply keeping the variable `TeX-file-line-error` to the
>   default value of non-nil.

See also [Uninformative error message when using AUCTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124246/31416)